# Maven - parent project requires child plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have forked a maven project (webservice) having a parent module and 3 child modules. One of the 3 modules is responsible for running the others and uses `tomee` plugin to run.

The documentation says: use `mvn clean package tomee:run` to run the web service.

If I run this command in the root directory, I get:

`No plugin found for prefix 'tomee' in the current project and in the plugin groups`

since the plugin is the child module `pom.xml`

And if I run the command in the child (runner) directory, I get:

`Failure to find **Another child module war file** in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository.`

From where I should run the command, and how it fix it? I don't think the pom.xml files structure have bugs. But I don't know how to run a project with multi modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to run:

`mvn clean install` and `mvn clean package`

In the parent module directory, then in the 2 child (not the runner) and finally in the runner child module I run:

`mvn clean install` and `mvn clean package tomee:run`

And it works.

For the future, I only run

`mvn clean package tomee:run`

In the runner child directory to start my project.